# Date Progress Bar PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I currently have this code:

```
$date1 = strtotime($row["progress"]);
$date2 = strtotime($time);
$today = time();
$num = $today - $date1;
$den = $date2 - $date1;
$percentage = ($today - $date1) / ($date2 - $date1) * 100;
echo "Current Completion Status:";
echo $percentage;
```

What it is supposed to do is come up with a progress status from today until the completion date. Which I will then use to create a progress bar.

However at the moment it shows 0 percent. I am using these test values for the progress row. This is 2015-11-17 12:00:00 and the current date in that format. So I can create the percentage. As stated it displays 0 as the result. How can I fix this to make it display percent completed.

Comment: Have you tried echoing parts of the expression to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes. It displays 102 if I set $date to a actual date without using the PHP date function. @KaspervandenBerg

Comment: Are the coding mistakes actually in your source? Missing single quotes around the date format on the call to `date()` and missing a semi-colon on the first echo line.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn fixed the mistakes. I tried it again but stil lthe same result.

Comment: There is no need for `$date = date('y-m-j&\nb\sp;g:i:s');` if you are just going to convert it back with `strtotime()`.  Just use `$date2 = time();` (but that is not going to change your outcome)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for the help. But yes as you said its the same result.

Comment: It does make a difference for me. http://codepad.viper-7.com/qXc69Y `strtotime()` appears unable to parse the complex format of `date('y-m-j&\nb\sp;g:i:s');` (which again doesn't appear necessary to this code block as posted)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if I change the date on your updated section the value wont change.

Comment: Are you certain of the value (and string format) of `$row['progress']`? As you can see in the codepad example, with the hard-coded date of 2015-11-17 12:00:00, it does produce a nonzero value.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski for some reason despite the it being the same value in MysQL database it wont function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and adapt it to your script:

```
$date = date('y-m-j&\nb\sp;g:i:s');

$date1 = strtotime('2015-03-12 00:00:00');
$date2 = strtotime('2015-12-17 00:00:00');
$today = time();

$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
$dateDiffForToday = $today - $date1;

$percentage = $dateDiffForToday / $dateDiff * 100;
$percentageRounded = round($percentage);

echo $percentageRounded . '%';
```

**$date2** shouldn't base on *date('y-m-j&\nb\sp;g:i:s')* because it's the same with **$today**.

Comment: Thanks. I did need to add a new collum with the start date for it to work.